# Missing QtCore

Tags: linux, qt

I am trying to build a package from source and ./configure tells me I am missing package QtCore.  Been googling & trying apt-get without success. Help please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called [libqt4-core](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libqt4-core) in Debian. Also, you'll need [qt4-dev-tools](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=qt4-dev-tools)