# QtCore is not accessed in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5

I'm trying to use QtCore in one of my projects, but vs code says "QtCore is not accessed". This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
```

I've been searching around, and I know this question has been asked before but when I try to get libqt4-core and qt4-dev-tools as a solution given from [This stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637948/missing-qtcore) but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might misunderstand that warning from VSCode. You normaly get this warning when you import something you don't use in the code.
You can ignore that warning or remove QtCore from your imports while you are not using it.